# Unknown error when uploading file using laravel

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel

When I try to upload an image file to the server, randomly it gives error and sometimes it works fine with no problems with the same file.

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpFoundation \ File \ Exception \ FileException 
The file "xxxxxx.jpg" was not uploaded due to an unknown error.
```

This is my code:

```
if (Input::hasFile('thumbnail_image')){
  // Upload Photo
  $thumbnailImage = Input::file('thumbnail_image');
  $filename = 'thumbnail.'.Input::file('thumbnail_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $destinationPath = 'training_product/article_id_'. $id .'/thumbnail_image';
  $databasePath = '/adidas/public/training_product/article_id_'. $id.'/thumbnail_image';
  $uploadFile = Input::file('thumbnail_image')->move($destinationPath, $filename);
  $product->thumbnail_images_path = $databasePath.'/'.$filename;
  $product->save();
}
```

Comment: Does your laravel log file contain any useful information?

Comment: the laravel log just return unknown error at the line 

$uploadFile = Input::file('thumbnail_image')->move($destinationPath, $filename); 

and i guess the file didnt upload but i dont know which setting is wrong and why sometimes work and sometimes didnt work

Comment: What happens if the file already exists in the target location ?

Answer (score 0):

What are your file permission on your destination folder? Try changing it to `777`(assuming that you are using a linux server: `sudo chmod -R 777 adidas/public/training_product`.

I've modified your code slightly and it works for me.

```

```
 if (Input::hasFile('thumbnail_image')){
      // Upload Photo
      $product = new Product;
      $thumbnailImage = Input::file('thumbnail_image');
      $ext = $thumbnailImage->guessExtension();
      $filename = 'thumbnail_'.  time()  . $ext;
      $destinationPath = 'training_product/article_id_'. $id .'/thumbnail_image';
      $databasePath = '/adidas/public/training_product/article_id_'. $id.'/thumbnail_image/';
      $thumbnailImage->move($destinationPath, $filename);
      $product->thumbnail_images_path = $databasePath . $filename;
      $product->save();
    }
```

```

I've Changed `getClientOriginalExtension()` to `guessExtension()`, instantiated a new `$product`, as I didn't see you doing. Also made sure the folder permissions would allow me to upload files.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i have changed the permission to 777 and the owner/group are correct.
i have changed to the code u did. it got errors at the function guess($path)

FileNotFoundException 
The file "/var/www/html/tmp/php1wJ9ca" does not exist